# How to dealing with JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

hello guys now i'm trying to convert my php code to json object and after that convert it to JS object and it gives me an error in the console said `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
but when i click to view my source code i found it converted to json object but gives me an error and i can't use the variable `tempPlayList` because this error .

```
<script>
   var tempSongIds = "<?php echo json_encode($album->getSongsids());?>";
   tempPlayList =  JSON.parse(tempSongIds);
 </script>
```

Comment: use `var tempSongIds = '<?php echo json_encode($album->getSongsids());?>';` - since JSON uses `"`

Comment: You're not going to send that JSON to a server are you? One of the most fundamental rules in web programming is to *never* trust the client.

Comment: no i receive it not send it

Answer (score 0):

use `var tempSongIds = '<?php echo json_encode($album->getSongsids());?>';` - since JSON uses "